# How to write an executable postgreSQL to calculate the average and percentage using this schema?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am learning SQL (self taught). I am trying to write an executable postgres SQL query to answer this question: Based on origin city (name), calculate the percentage of trips where the payment
was at least 10% greater than the average for trips originating in that city.

Context: 1) A completed trip is defined as one with status ‘completed’ in the rentals table. 2) Only considering trips in the last 30 days.

What I started with (hoping this looks good):

```
SELECT n.name, r.origin_id, SUM(r.fare_dollars), AVG(r.fare_dollars), count(r.id)
FROM rentals r, neighborhood n
LEFT JOIN r ON r.origin_id = n.id
GROUP BY n.name;
```

On the right track?!

What I need your help with (if I am correct about this approach):

The question will require that I do a subquery that will pull all of the records to see how it compares to the average fare. Then I will need to write another query that will tell me which of those rides were 10% higher than the average fare.

I look forward to seeing any insights you may be able to provide! Do let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Thanks.

Comment: your question is not clear. The first thing I could say you're confused with comma seperated join format and ansi-92 join format, and the second formatting style(ansi-92) should be preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're thinking in the right direction, your querying skills are not yet there though, right? I'll try to explain to the best of my ability, hope you follow along (and if you can't, feel free to ask).

So first, what you need to know is what's the average fare per origin:

```
SELECT n.id, n.name, AVG(r.fare_dollars) AS average_fare
  FROM neighborhood n
  JOIN rentals r
    ON r.origin_id = n.id
 GROUP BY n.id, n.name
```

That's a fairly simple query, though normally you wouldn't need id here. We're going to use this query to compare against individual rides though, so we'll just join it to our rentals table:

```
SELECT avg_per_neighborhood.name 
     , SUM(CASE 
            WHEN r.fare_dollars >= avg_per_neighborhood.average_fare * 1.1 THEN 1.0 
            ELSE 0 
          END) / COUNT(*) AS percAbove110
  FROM rentals r
  JOIN (SELECT n.id, n.name, AVG(r.fare_dollars) AS average_fare
          FROM neighborhood n
          JOIN rentals r
            ON r.origin_id = n.id
         GROUP BY n.id, n.name) avg_per_neighborhood
    ON r.origin_id = avg_per_neighborhood.id
 GROUP BY avg_per_neighborhood.name
```

The interesting part is of course the percentage above 10% higher than the average part; so first we determine whether or not the individual rental is higher than the joined average * 1.1 (or, 110% of the average), and if it is return 1, or return 0 if it isn't - that's the `CASE` statement. We sum these up per neighborhood (`SUM(CASE ... END)`) and divide by the total number of rides in that neighborhood (`COUNT(*)`), giving us the percentage.

This query can be rewritten a little bit using window functions:

```
SELECT subq.NAME
     , SUM(subq.isHigherThan110avg) / COUNT(*) AS percAbove110
  FROM (SELECT n.NAME
             , CASE 
                 WHEN r.fare_dollars > 1.1 * AVG(r.fare_dollars) OVER (PARTITION BY n.id) THEN 1.0 
                 ELSE 0 
               END AS isHigherThan110avg
          FROM neighborhood n
          JOIN rentals r
            ON r.origin_id = n.id
     ) subq
 GROUP BY subq.name
```

Here the `subq` subquery does the comparison against the average inline, using the `AVG(...) OVER (...)` window function, and the outer query just aggregates the results.

[Working example on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9785fe5ab0046529da6d52f3c820acf1)

You'll of course need to apply your own filters, like the completed and last 30 days, but you get the gist of it I hope.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. It is thorough and so helpful. Much appreciated! And yes, I am not quite there yet with my querying skills, but I will be soon enough. Thanks, again!

Comment: No problem at all. If possible, consider upvoting my answer so that users who find this question in the future know it's correct and helped.

Comment: Sure thing! I do have one more question as I am not sure that I did this correctly. How would you add the filters, i.e. completed and last 30 days to this sql?

Comment: Just add them after the join, `WHERE r.status = 'Completed' AND r.date_completed > current_date - interval '30 days'` or something like that (I don't know your column names).

Comment: Thanks! I was not totally off on this part, which is great. I accepted your answer and did as you requested and got the following: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. Either way, I accepted it and it does work for anyone reading this! Many thanks, again. I will certainly have more questions as I try to better my querying skills.

Comment: Ah right, you can't upvote because you're new, sorry! Cheers and good luck, do not hesitate to ask once you're stuck and remember the best way to learn is by trying.